# Applescript to catalog Filename and Filepath

Tags: applescript, posix, filepath

I need track files being sent out to various vendors.  I store them in a Filemaker database, but have been trying to develop more efficient ways to fill my database.  I created an automator app to create this list for me, but since the "Filter Finder items" relies on Spotlight, it doesn't work on networked drives.

mcgrailm made a slick Applescript that helps me populate a list of the files themselves.  This is sufficient for about 90% of my needs as usually I just need to keep a record that a file has been sent, but sometimes I need to also track the POSIX filepath to tell a recipient where on the drive the files are located.

mcgrailm's script was

tell application "Finder"
    set file_list to name of every file of entire contents of (choose folder with prompt "Please select directory.")
   end tell

Does anybody know how I can modify this script to give me the full POSIX filepath along with the filename?  I tried modifying but my Applescript skills are pretty lacking.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`entire contents` in Finder could be very slow. A much faster solution is

```
set theFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Please select directory.")
set file_list to do shell script "find " & quoted form of theFolder & " -type f ! -name '.*'"
```

the result is plain text. One full POSIX path per line.

If you want a list use

```
set file_list to paragraphs of (do shell script "find " & quoted form of theFolder & " -type f ! -name '.*'")
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, at the fourth folder level, it doubled up the slash.  Example:

/Volumes/SOURCES/03_OUTPUTS//03 MAR/03.31.15/filename

Also, it's show reference to a file that isn't there

/Volumes/SOURCES/03_OUTPUTS//03 MAR/03.31.15/._filename

I'm assuming that's a delete or renamed file.  Is there a way to exclude that?

Comment: Yes, could be, but the paths are usable

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is great!

Comment: I updated the post to exclude invisible files (starting with `.`)

Comment: That's awesome!  I can run it individual folders, but it stops me with an error when I run it on the root of an external drive. .DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission Denied.  I'm going to dig around to see how to get around that, but you've been incredibly generous and helpful, I really appreciate it.